# How to select from a group

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, regex-group

I am so lost on how to grab this. I've been using https://regexr.com/ and https://www.logextender.com/ but I got nothin. Can anyone help this poor newbie?

I'm trying to grab everything after " | ".

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="atw-JobInfo-companyLocation"><span>CG-VAK Softwares USA Inc</span><span> | </span><span>Remote </span></div>
```

My Regular Expression so far is:

> (([\w-.]+[-.][\w-.]+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+|\s+(\w+)\s+)

My table looks like the following and I want to separate the company name from everything aft " | ", but I think the best way is through regular expression after creating the table? Halp.

```
+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|                     Position                      |               Company                |
+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Renovation/Construction Underwriter               | Ignite Human Capital | Remote        |
| Scientific Computing                              | CG-VAK Softwares USA Inc | Remote    |
| Data Analytics Engineer                           | Delta Defense LLC | West Bend, WI    |
| Data Analyst - Tableau - Alteryx - Insurance e... | Grapevine Technology | United States |
| Technology Integration Specialist                 | KAGE Innovation | Osceola, WI        |
+---------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: will there be only one `|` symbol in a given string ? And also what kind of input are you expecting ? company from table or html or both ?

Comment: I should update this. I'm using python to pull from an html file so that I can turn my content into a table with columns: Position, Company, Location)

Comment: if there is only one `|` symbol then you can just use `\|(.*)` ? and `\1` will be everything after `|`

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with simply splitting?

```py
sample = 'CG-VAK Softwares USA Inc | Remote'

parts = sample.split('|')
if len(parts) == 2:
    print(parts[1].strip()) # prints 'Remote'
```

if you already have the table you should do it with that data. if you are starting with html, an html parsing library can create it easily:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def find_span_texts(html):
    """find spans and return their containing text

    the parameter is a bs4.element.Tag, or partial result from a BS instance
    the return is an array of strings, representing the contenxt of the spans
    """
    return [s.text for s in html.find_all('span')]


html_input = """<div class="atw-JobInfo-companyLocation">
    <span>CG-VAK Softwares USA Inc</span>
    <span> | </span><span>Remote </span></div>"""

# create soup object
bs = BS(html_input, 'html.parser')

# find divs with information class
divs = bs.find_all(['div', {"class":"atw-JobInfo-companyLocation"}])

# get spans from all spans
spanTexts = [find_span_texts(div) for div in divs]
# print(spanTexts) # [['CG-VAK Softwares USA Inc', ' | ', 'Remote ']]

# get company and location
coLocs = [[c.strip(), l.strip()] for c, pipe, l in spanTexts]

# show result
print(coLocs) # [['CG-VAK Softwares USA Inc', 'Remote']]
```

Comment: Just print every 3rd and this would be golden.